# Grouping numbers into the fewest fix-sized groups based on a range

Tags: dynamic-programming

Suppose I have a group that can hold numbers with these two criteria:

1. It has a range of 5 i.e. the difference between the lowest and highest number can be up to 5.
2. Each group can hold a maximum of 4 numbers.

e.g. if I have numbers `1,2,3,4,6,8,10,11,13,16,17,18`. How do I go about grouping these numbers in the fewest number of windows possible? two possible answers:

1. `[1,2,3,4],[6,8,10,11],[13,16,17,18]`
2. `[1,2,3],[4,6,8],[10,11,13],[16,17,18]`

Maybe this is not the best example, but is there a programming problem that is similar to this?

Comment: Can you construct a solution where a strategy other than 'pack as many numbers as you can into each group before moving onto the next group', isn't as good (in terms of number of groups) as some other strategy?

Answer (score 1):

That's not a good problem for dynamic programming. A greedy algorithm is enough.

Here is a very rough sketch of a proof that greedy is enough.

**(remark-1)** Suppose that `[x1, x2, ..., xN]` is your input sequence of numbers and `[(1 = l1, r1), (l2, r2), ..., (lM, rM = N)]` are pairs of indices between 1 and N which describe the `(start, end)` of a window, such that all those windows together satisfy your constraints and cover all numbers in the sequence. Now remove `xN`. Obviously, the old cover of `[x1, ..., xN]` can be transformed into a new cover `[(1 = l1, r1), ..., (lM, N - 1)]` of `[x1, ..., x{N-1}]`, and it has at most as many (or one fewer) windows as the old cover.

**(induction)** Now make an induction over `N` to show that the greedy "cut-as-much-as-you-can-from-the-end-of-the-list"-algorithm is optimal.

- For `[x1]` the greedy algorithm finds the cover `[(1, 1)]`, which is obviously optimal.
- Assume that the greedy algorithm finds the optimal covering for `[x1, ..., xK]` for all K < N. Let `M` be the smallest index such that `xN - xM <= maxWindowWidth` and `N - M <= maxElemsPerWindow`. Let `Z` be the optimal number of windows that is required to cover `[x1, ..., x{M - 1}]`. If we choose `(M', N)` as the last window for any `M' > M`, then by (remark-1) the solution `Z'` for `[x1, ..., x{M'}]` will be equal or worse than `Z`, that is, `Z' >= Z`, and we will need `(Z' + 1) >= (Z + 1)` windows in total. Since the greedy algorithm always cuts away as many elements as possible, it will choose `(M, N)` as the last window, and end up with `(Q + 1)` windows in total, where `Q` is the number of windows the greedy algorithm will use to cover `[x1, ..., x{M-1}]`. But by induction assumption `Q = Z`, and thus the greedy algorithm will need `Z + 1` windows, which is equal or better than any other solution `Z' + 1`.

Hence, the greedy algorithm is optimal.

Here is a sketch in Scala:

```
def greedyCoverByWindows(
  numbers: List[Int], 
  maxWindowWidth: Int,
  maxElemsPerWindow: Int
): List[List[Int]] = numbers match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case h :: t => {
    val window = h :: t.take(maxElemsPerWindow - 1).filter(_ - h <= maxWindowWidth)
    val rest = t.drop(window.size - 1)
    window :: greedyCoverByWindows(rest, maxWindowWidth, maxElemsPerWindow)
  }
}

val example = List(1,2,3,4,6,8,10,11,13,16,17,18)
val maxWindowWidth = 5
val maxElemsPerWindow = 4

val cover = greedyCoverByWindows(example, maxWindowWidth, maxElemsPerWindow)

println(example)
println(cover)

// Output:
// List(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 16, 17, 18)
// List(List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(6, 8, 10, 11), List(13, 16, 17, 18))
```